# Cannot Get Rid of Application Window After Application Crashes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

I'm trying to debug a VS 2008 command-line application running under Windows XP. The application has been crashing (access violation), and I am catching the crsah in the debuuger. After looking at the call stack, etc., I tell the IDE to "Stop Debugging". The application window remains, but the process does not appear in Task Manager. Nothing happens when I click the "X" in the upper-right corner, though I can minimze / restore the window. The process is normally shut down by pressing Esc. It does not respond to this keypress.

I cannot even get rid of the application window by attempting to reboot XP. The machine will not reboot; it simply ignores my command to do so.

The only way I've been able to get rid of the application window is to do a hard power cycle. Ughh...

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to clean up this lingering application window after the application crashes?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Strange question.  Do you really want to know how to deal with a borked operating system instead of learning how to fix the access violation exception in your program?  Focusing on the egg instead of teh chicken might be best here.  Do post an answer if you ever find out how XP got destabilized this badly.

Comment: Certainly, the debugging is the point. However, the code is not mine and it is extremely complex. It is going to be a protracted debugging effort. Since every application re-start in the debugging process is going to entail a hard power-down, I'd rather find a way to kill the process so that I don't risk corrupting anything by performing these hard power-downs. In addition, it is very time-consuming to repeatedly cycle power.